# Grails assets directory management

Tags: grails

To my Grails project, I use ztree library.
In the css of this library, we have the following :

```
background-image:url("/ztree/img/zTreeStandard.png")
```

I have 3 directory in assets/

```
images/
javascripts/
stylesheets/
```

I don't want to modify the css to change the path of **background-image:url("/ztree/img/zTreeStandard.png")**.
So, here are my questions :

- Is that mandatory to create a ztree directory in assets/ ?
- Can I put ztree directory in images/ ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the image at `grails-app/assets/images/ztree/img/zTreeStandard.png`, the assets-pipeline plugin *should* be able to resolve it (I haven't tested this). If it doesn't work, the reason will be because of the leading `/` in the path

```
background-image:url("/ztree/img/zTreeStandard.png")
```

I understand that you don't like modifying 3rd party code, but I don't think you'll have any choice other than to change this to

```
background-image:url("ztree/img/zTreeStandard.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a `assets/vendor` directory and you can just dump all your third-party libraries in there. It should be smart enough for you not have to change any paths--though the absolute URLs might mess things up since usually grails is running at `http://host:port/app-name/`.